# How can I display HTML in a <div> with Angular 1.2.0 - rc2

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display some HTML in my web page and using the following:

```
        xx {{ pageHtml }} yy 

        <div data-ng-bind-html-unsafe="$scope.pageHtml"></div>
```

The data between xx and yy shows up as raw HTML but what I want is to not show it as raw. I used the code on the second line but nothing shows.

Is there something I am missing? Did something change in 1.2 because I thought this was working before?

**Update** - I do 100% trust the HTML and don't want to clean it. There will be code inside the HTML that needs to show on the screen.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

By default the innerHTML-ed expression result is sanitized using the `$sanitize` service which would require you to include `ngSanitize` in your module's dependencies.

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="pageHtml"></div>
```

However if you trust the HTML to be safe, you can bypass sanitization using `$sce` service that you would inject in your controller:

```
$scope.someSafeContent = $sce.trustAsHtml("<i>Hello</i> <b>World!</b>");
```

HTML:

```
<!-- bypasses sanitizaton -->
<div data-ng-bind-html="someSafeContent"></div>
```

Comment: What does it mean "include ngSanitize". What is that used for ?

Comment: Would you mind to point me to the document that tells us about the fact that ngSanitize will be needed? Because i am pretty sure that i used ng-bind-html without that module a while ago

Comment: I didn't yet add the ngSanitize (will do very soon) but without that and with your exact code I don't see anything at all except raw HTML between xx and yy.

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

myApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });

**In View**

This will resolve your problem.