# Bold specific words doesn't display b tags angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I am creating an Angular JS app and i get a text from the server that i need to display in my site.
The text i got from server :

```
"My name is <b> John </b>" with b tags.
```

Unfortunately, when I display it every one notify the strong text tags.

```
  {{text}}
```

I would like that users will see only "John" in bold.
Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display HTML in a <div> with Angular 1.2.0 - rc2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760703/how-can-i-display-html-in-a-div-with-angular-1-2-0-rc2)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010650/bold-specific-words-doesnt-display-b-tags-angular-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010650/bold-specific-words-doesnt-display-b-tags-angular-js)

Answer (score 3):

**[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/OxbjmxAEHGZUyYVU4130?p=preview)**

You can use `ng-bind-html` as @CAT suggested, but if you don't want to go as much as use [`$sce.trustAsHtml()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml) explicitly you can use this directive:

```
  .directive('htmlSafe', function($parse, $sce) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        var html = attr.ngBindHtml;
        if(angular.isDefined(html)) {
          var getter = $parse(html);
          var setter = getter.assign;
          setter(scope, $sce.trustAsHtml(getter(scope)));
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

and then you can use it like this in your html:

```
<div ng-bind-html="html" html-safe></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's normal behavior, it's happening because of Angular's sanitize. You can't just print out html tags. You need to use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).