# Generate Menu Html and bind div from Angularjs and mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am generating html menu string from XML in mvc controller and in angularjs i am passing the response to div like $("#divId").html(response).

Its working fine but some menus have sub menus so the open class is not calling so its not showing the submenus

please tell where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In angular, never use $() outside a directive (and generally use angular.element() instead ... But anyway you don't need it 99% of the time) 
If you want to dynamically add some HTML into an angular template use the ng-bind-html property.

In your controller

```
$scope.mymenu = response;
```

In your html

```
<div ng-bind-html="response"></div>
```

You'll probably run into a case that angular don't trust your HTML. You'll have to use some angular services to say angular that your HTML should be trust (if it is a proper source).

Here is a good topic on [how to make angular trust your HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18760742/2516560)

Hope it helped.

### EDIT

Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OW7ayqyf0utmcnnEDjBB?p=preview) of this proposition

Looks like the first problem is that you try to write your HTML into the controller, wich is a bad thing.

Instead you should try to generate a JS object like this one :

```
$scope.mymenu = [{
  name:"Adminitstration",
  url:"/Administration",
},{
  name: "My Dashboard",
  url:"/mydashboard",
  submenus: [{
    name:"Activity dashboard",
    url:"/activity",
  }]
},{
  name: "Profiles",
  url:"/profiles",
  submenus: [{
    name:"Accounts",
    url:"/accounts",
  }]
}]
```

And use the angular templating to render an HTML according to theses

```
<ul>
  <li ng-click="menu.submenusShow = !menu.submenusShow" ng-repeat="menu in mymenu">
    <a href="{{menu.submenus.length ? '#' : menu.url}}">{{menu.name}}</a>
    <ul ng-show="menu.submenusShow">
      <li  ng-repeat="submenu in menu.submenus">
        <a href="{{menu.url+submenu.url}}">{{submenu.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No its working fine but sub-menus not showing as class open is not calling to show submenus

Comment: @NeetuMaheshwari I didn't really understand what is not working. Anyway what are you trying to do ? You just want some sub-menus to show when you click on the main menu items right ? Could you add the CSS / JS doing this job ?

Comment: Yes I want  sub-menus to show when you click on the main menu items . Its working fine when static but when I generate html from controller and bind from angularjs, these submenus are not showing

Comment: @NeetuMaheshwari What do you use to do that ?

Comment: generate html from controller  then call method from angularjs and bind the response in div like both way $("$divid").html(response) / ng-bind-html="response"  but sub-menus are not showing

Comment: @NeetuMaheshwari How do you generate the HTML from you controller ? I'll update my answer with a proposition.

Comment: @NeetuMaheshwari I added a plunker with a proposition of how you should do this in an angular way.

Comment: I am generating the complete html from controller like "<ul><li ><a href='/Program/Index' >g</a></li><li ><ul><li><a href='/MyDashboard/Index'  >Activity Dashboard</a></li><li><a href='/MyDashboard/Calendar'  title='Calendar'>Calendar</a></li><li class=''><a href='/MyDashboard/TaskAct'  title='Task & activites'>Task & activites</a></li><li class=''><a href='/MyDashboard/Mailbox'  title='Mailbox'>Mailbox</a></li><li class=''><a href='/MyDashboard/Chat'  title='Chat'>Chat</a></li></ul></li></ul>" and calling the method from angularjs  and binding this response in div